# problem in copying data from assets to application

Tags: android, database

For my application i need to read data from my own data base. I put my db in "ASSETS" folder and using following code to copy into the path

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.android.example/databases/"
```

But the table is not getting created.And its throwing exception and forced close.

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}
```

In above code "buffer" is not getting data . so its not writing data to myOutput. I found this code in net and modified . could any body help me to read the file in assets folder to SD card.I need to store data in SD card from external file and read from it.

Comment: What exception do you get? Can you attach log?

Answer (score 1):

Check you database file size, there is a limitation around 1.2 Mb for files in the "assets" folder.
One way around it is to use the Unix "split" command, add the split files in the res/raw folder, and then splice them back together into the db by altering the code you have slightly.
Read this blog (http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You must put data not in `ASSETS` folder but into `assets` - please double check!