# How to read data from .db file

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have prebuild DB file. with data base name and the schema related to the table.

I have "abc" table in my MyData.db file.

Please let me know how to read all the data from 'abc' table.

Please provide me code snippet to get the data.

thanks.

Comment: Refer this [copying-database-file-from-assets-to-data-data-folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505903/copying-database-file-from-assets-to-data-data-folder-in-file-explorer-andro/18506387#18506387)

Comment: Then, we should also give you a tutorial on how to INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE data... Don't you have Google? There's a plenty of tutorials on CRUD operations in Android + SQLite.

Comment: Increase your repo. Due to 404, you didn't get anything. Try Google.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many tutorials available in web. For your information I am attaching one of the link here

Crud oprations on Db : [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Access database from assets [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949629/2009591)